# Lookup with multiple criteria with last date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want the result of the formula to be $28 because it matches the last date.

Thanks

| Date | Item | Size | Color | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04-11-2022 | T-shirt | Large | Red | $17 |
| 05-11-2022 | T-shirt | Large | Red | $28 |

```
=INDEX(E2:E6,MATCH(1,(H2=B2:B6)*(H3=C2:C6)*(H4=D2:D6),0))
```

[image: result formula]

[image: result formula2]

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya , thanks for the reply from you but if I use this formula `=INDEX(E2:E3,MATCH(1,(H2=B2:B6)*(H3=C2:C6)*(H4=D2:D6)*(A2:A6<>""),1))` result 0

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya , I've used `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` the result is 0 and I use excel 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could try using a formula like as shown below using `LOOKUP()` Function, provided the dates are sorted in ascending order.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H5`

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((H2=B2:B3)*(H3=C2:C3)*(H4=D2:D3)*(A2:A3<>"")),E2:E3)
```

---

However, if your dates are not sorted then you can try using the below formula, to get latest date price.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `K2`

```
   =INDEX($E$2:$E$6,MATCH(1,INDEX((MAX(IF((I2=$C$2:$C$6)*(J2=$D$2:$D$6)*(H2=$B$2:$B$6),
$A$2:$A$6,""))=$A$2:$A$6)*(I2=$C$2:$C$6)*(J2=$D$2:$D$6)*(H2=$B$2:$B$6),),0))
```

---

**Note:** Depending on one's Excel version this may needs to be keyed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.